# iAd Contract Expired? Not so, says iTunesConnect. iAd Module thinks otherwise

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, iad

I recently updated my Developer membership. My new contract went into effect May 19th. Last week I went in and browsed my iAd earnings, and noticed that all of my iAd apps are "Red" and not receiving ads. After expanding the details to find out why, the iAd module tells me that my iAd contract has expired. However, the Contracts, Banking and Tax module reports that everything is OK, and my iAd contract will be in effect until May 19, 2013.

Incidentally, my last day of revenue was May 19th of this year.

I called Apple Support, have had a follow up phone call where it was requested I submit screenshots, but I haven't heard anything back.  Has anyone else experienced this?

[image: iAdContract page]

[image: iAd Revenue Page]

Comment: Halt!  Be that a VM or do mine eyes see a Mac developer using Windows... '95.  *BLASPHEMY!* Anyhow, support takes up to a month to get back to you.

Comment: Just logging in from work, we're bound to our Windows XP with shackles

Comment: The same problem here. I updated de Developer Membership and the same day the iAd network turn off. And the contract expires in 2013! Apple has solved the problem for you?

Comment: Yes, but it took longer than a month. I had to call dev relations and have a ticket created. I got a call back a few days later to clarify. After a couple more weeks I received an email that it had been fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the solution to this problem is, as experienced by myself and Justin:

- call (not write to) the iOS Developer Program Support (not the technical support: that's useless). You will find the number here: https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone.php
- no waiting time. They reply right away
- explain the problem keeping in mind that the people at Dev Program Support do not have iTunesConnect: they only can see that your contract is OK
- they will send you an email in which they ask for screenshots
- send them screenshots and a detailed description of the problem
- in 3/4 days, you will receive an email saying your problem has been transferred to a Senior Consultant
- in 10 days, you will receive an email saying your problem's being solved
- in 14 days (my case), your problem will be solved and ads will restart coming.

Comment: Very helpful advice, thank you. For me it was resolved in 8h, the secret was asking to be transferred to **iTunes Provider Support** on calling Developer Support. See my answer for the full details.

Answer (score 4):

Having the exact same problem. Master agreements say my iAd contract is valid until October 2013, whereas the iAd module affirms I will not receive ads because "my iAd contract has expired" (no option to renew it is yet presented).
I Wrote to the iAd support with detailed screenshots. As a first reply they said something that had nothing to do with the issue (they wrote that I could not enable iAds  when the application is "Ready for sale" - too bad iAds where already enabled). They suggested re-submitting the app.
I wrote back specifying the problem was with the inconsistency between iAd module and the contracts module. They wrote they would forward the problem to a technical team. Two days later I have not had any news. 
This is frustrating, because it applies to all of my iAd-enabled apps and I feel very stupid to have paid $80 to renew my developer program and reading this was not properly recorded :(

Comment: Ok, mine only worked itself out after I called dev relations. I had them enter a trouble ticket. It didn't take very many days but a support member called me back, got more info, and then a few days after that dev relations emailed to say the problem had been fixed. You should call them up, I don't think emailing helps.

Comment: Understood. I'll try that and report :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and I followed Rick_puglia's [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13418680/72176) (big thank you!) and phoned support.  For me it was resolved in under 8 hours, here my tale:

Important: You need to talk to the **iTunes Provider Support** department of Apple Developer Support. They are the ones who can really help with iTunes connect issues.  Their office hours are 9am to 5pm PST (San Francisco Time). I was told I could be transferred to them from any Apple developer support line *during those hours*. I waited till their office opened, and called back using the `1 (800)…` American number from [the list](https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone.php).

I called that number and asked to be transferred to iTunes Provider Support. I was asked a few quick questions to make sure that was the department I needed, and was transferred.

Once transferred, the iTunes Provider Support guy checked my account and confirmed what I saw (he could see that in the IAD portal it said expired, but in iTunes connect Contracts section it was not). He told me he would bump it up the chain, created a ticket and gave me the case number.

I went to sleep, woke up 8h later and everything was resolved.

Comment: This is happening to me right now. My app is a Christmas app and tomorrow is a peak day for me. Unbelievable.

Answer (score 2):

FYI: Apple is no longer renewing iAd accounts as they are shutting down the entire system at the end of June.  Source: just got off the phone with Apple Dev Connect